# need to capture NULL in a query

Tags: postgresql

I have a query that shows success rate for staff and works splendidly except:  If staff "Bob" has not had any activity in the date range, he will not appear in the results.  If he had at least one code in the query it would result in a 0% or 100%.  If there are no codes attached to his name, he does not show in the results.  I have seen an example of - 
ISNULL(s.code, 'No Entry') AS NoContact   to use but I guess I am not using it correctly
and I just cannot figure out  how to add it into the query.  Can someone assist?

Here is the current query that works great (but omits any staff who do not have any of the codes:

```
SELECT st.staff_id
,round((count(s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403') OR NULL) * 100.0)
/ count(*), 1) AS successes
-- unsuccessful code is 10405
FROM   notes n 
JOIN   services s  ON s.zzud_service = n.zrud_service
JOIN   staff st ON st.zzud_staff = n.zrud_staff
WHERE n.date_service >= DATE '07/01/2014' AND n.date_service <= CURRENT_DATE
--    n.date_service BETWEEN (now() - '30 days'::interval) AND now()
AND  s.code IN ('10401','10402','10403','10405')
GROUP  BY st.staff_id;
```

Here is a sample result:

```
Staff    SuccessRate      Explination
Sam      100%            (has 1 successful and 0 unsuccessful)
Joe       50%            (has 1 successful and 1 unsuccessful)
Amy        0%            (has 1 unsuccessful)
```

Bob does not show         ( no discharges in the date range)

Comment: You just need to `LEFT JOIN` your staff to that table rather than using `JOIN` (which implies an `INNER JOIN`). You should also specify that your `JOIN`s are `INNER JOIN`s explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  I changed the first join to INNER JOIN and the join to the staff table to LEFT JOIN.  But, the results were the same

Answer (score 3):

Since you place the `staff` table at the end you need to `right join` it and move the conditions to the join conditions.

```
select
    st.staff_id,
    round(
        count(s.code in ('10401','10402','10403') or null) * 100.0
        /
        count(*)
    , 1) as successes
-- unsuccessful code is 10405
from
    notes n 
    inner join
    services s on
        s.zzud_service = n.zrud_service and
        n.date_service >= date '07/01/2014' and
        n.date_service <= current_date
    right join
    staff st on
        st.zzud_staff = n.zrud_staff
    --    n.date_service between (now() - '30 days'::interval) and now()
        and s.code in ('10401','10402','10403','10405')
group by st.staff_id;
```